# Une traduction de « vreemd genoeg »

Tags: traduction, adverbes, néerlandais

Je cherche un mot pour introduire un fait qui étonne le lecteur, à savoir *vreemd genoeg*. Ce mot sert à souligner qu'un fait est dingue. Je vous explique le fonctionnement du mot cherché par le biais de trois exemples. Je l'écrirai *étrangement* pour désigner le mot voulu :

- « La tortue est pourvu d'une armure pour se rétracter quand un des animaux la harcèle. *Étrangement*, beaucoup de tortues savent mordre très durement. »
- « Pendant l'été, les moustiques piquent avec leur trompe. La femelle pique des mammifères pour rassembler du sang et pondre ses œufs. *Étrangement*, les mâles ne piquent pas, bien qu'ils sont habilités corporellement pour le faire. »
- « Une denrée qui est, *étrangement*, vraiment vendue: Un crayon pré-maché. »

Ce mot a quelque chose en commun avec *cependant* : il s'emploie lorsque deux parties d'un *propos* semblent se frotter.
Il se distingue de *cependant* par les faits suivants : on l'emploie si une partie d'un propos laisse penser quelque chose tandis qu'un propos suivant ou préalable contredit cette pensée légèrement.
Les deux parties s'accompagnent mal ; ensemble, elles éveillent de l'étonnement. On entend le mot *néanmoins* plutôt quand le fait prononcé est moins raccordable avec la jugeote. J'ai un peu de mal à décrire comment il me semble que ces mots diffèrent.

Cela est-il suffisant pour reconnaître une tournure française qui traduit *vreemd genoeg* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si le fait est « étonnant », l'idéal me semble être *étonnamment*.

Answer (score 6):

En un seul mot : curieusement, étrangement, bizarrement, pourtant...

Comment: +1 pour bizarrement